# Cant handle DoesNotExist error with nested resources

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble handling DoesNotExist error, Im using DRF and DRF-Nested-Routers and when I create a new Like object I need the Photo PK so I can add it to the Like object.

I'm trying to catch the error that I get when the Photo with that PK doesn't exist.
This is how I'm doing the creation of the Like in the serializer:

```
class LikeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Like model serializer. """

    user = serializers.CharField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        """ Meta class. """

        model = Like
        fields = ('user', 'photo')
        read_only_fields = ('user', 'photo')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Get the photo pk from the view context (DRF-nested-routers) and
        # create the new like with the validated_data
        photo_pk = self.context['view'].kwargs["photo_pk"]
        try:
            photo = Photo.objects.get(id=photo_pk)
        except Photo.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(data={'detail': "The photo doesn't exist."}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        validated_data["photo"] = photo
        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)
        if created:
            photo.total_likes += 1
            photo.save()
        return like
```

The perform_create of the view:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    """ Creates a new like.

    The substraction in the total_likes is made in the serializer.
    """
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The response I get with this is: `{'user': 'my username here'}`

I also tried with `except Photo.DoesNotExist` but it gives the same result.

Comment: Can you share the request data and the whole serializer?

Comment: You have written: `photo_pk = self.context['view'].kwargs["photo_pk"]`, you are sure that the context of the serializer contains these objects? Please provide full error details.

Comment: I added more of the code, the complete serializer and the perform_create.
Yes, the context has the photo_pk, the error I get is `Photo.DoesNotExist: Photo matching query does not exist.` But that's fine, the problem is that I get the wrong response when trying to handle that error. The response I get (`{'user': 'my username here'}`) is the `self.data` of the serializer, if that helps. I don't understand why it doesn't give the response part of the `except DoesNotExist:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It migth be more clear to perform the check in the validate method of the serializer class. In case of photo absence raise the `serializers.ValidationError`.

I have not test the code but I think that it works.

```py
class LikeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    ...

    def validate(self, attrs):
        photo_pk = self.context['view'].kwargs["photo_pk"]
        try:
            photo = Photo.objects.get(id=photo_pk)
        except Photo.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"detail": "The photo doesn't exist"})
        attrs["photo"] = photo
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Get the photo pk from the view context (DRF-nested-routers) and
        # create the new like with the validated_data
        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)
        if created:
            photo.total_likes += 1
            photo.save()
        return like
```

```py
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    """ Creates a new like.

    The substraction in the total_likes is made in the serializer.
    """
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        raise ValidationError(serializer.errors)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: That works! But I needed to add `photo = Photo.objects.get(id=photo_pk)` to the create method, and it already does that query in `validate()`, any idea how I can do it just once? Like maybe just in `validate()` and then pass it to the create method?